# Redirection or canonical? URL changed

Tags: seo, google-search-console, 301-redirect, rel-canonical, link-juice

We've changed one of the url in the website, the content of the page remains same.

Its been a month, but google is still showing the old URL in the search result.

What should be done here?

1. 301 redirection from old url to new url?
2. Canonical tag to show the correct url?
3. If we remove 301 redirection, the current url from SERP is going to 404.

Please please let me know as we wish to show the new url in SERP but also don't want to miss the Link juice of old url.

Thanks
AB

Comment: Are you currently using a 301 redirect or are you showing the same content on both URLs?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need to offer both pages, you should prefer a 301 redirect over rel canonical:

- If Google thinks the "wrong" page is a better match for the user's intent, it will ignore rel=canonical.  Google is less apt to ignore 301 redirects.
- It's easier to maintain a 301 redirect than to maintain a duplicate page.
- Visitors are more likely to link/bookmark your new site if your old site 301s to your new site.

To a limited extent, you can  [Request Indexing](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289#request_indexing) of specific pages.  Manually reindexing problematic pages might help.

Comment: Thank you Brian. I appreicate.